# Sum values besides variable size merged cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with the following structure: There are *entities* with unique *id*-s. Each entity has one or more *components*. The *components* have multiple *number fields*. My task is to calculate the sum of the *components number fields* for each *entity* using only basic excel feautres (No VBA, no external scripting).

The problem is with the input format. Here is a little sketch of the problem and with the expected result. Every entity are represented as multiple rows in the spreadsheet. The *ID* and *SUM* fields are merged for an entity, individual rows represent components, number fields are never merged (although sometimes they are just empty). There are 4000 such rows, the structure should not be changed (people using the sheet are used to it, and looks good in printing), the sum fields are initially merged but empty. (I think somebody assembled the sheet by hand long ago).

[image]

My thought was to use `SUMIF` in a formula, but I couldn't access the *ID* field for the individual rows (components) after the first one in each entity. Looks like excel handles merged cells like the upper-left corner is the cell itself, and all the others are empty. The other problem I ran into is that I cannot apply a formula for the whole SUM column. I tried to select the first cell and drag the little dot in the bottom-right corner, but it refused to do so because the merged cells are of diffrent sizes.

Any idea how could I calculate the SUM field using basic excel and formulas, without VBA and without entering a formula for all the 4000 rows by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column (see screenshot). Then use SUMIF

[image]

You can hide the helper column.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign names to ranges.
Here are the steps to assign them:

1. Select the range you want to assign a name for
2. On the left side of the bar, where you can assign a function formula, you will see your selected cell range. Click on it to open a dropdown menu
3. Find the option "Manage named ranges", on the very bottom of the dropdown. Click it and a sidebar will open on the right side.
4. Set the name for the range that you want to use and click "Done"

After these steps you will be able to use the variable name in any formula you need